# 'SC' is not defined when using soundcloud SDK

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, jshint

JS hint is giving me a `'SC' is not defined` when using soundcloud SDK

`SC.whenStreamingReady( function() {`
'SC' is not defined

I'm prepending a variety of js files before my main file - and smashing them together... master has a jQuery closure because this is a WordPress project.

(jQuery is called by default because this is based around a WordPress install)

PREPENDED js files
fastclick (bower)
velocity (bower)
soundcloudSDK (vendor)

(all combined with)
MASTER FILE 
master-script.js:

```
(function($){
// =============================================

"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {

    // get track ready
    var topDown = function() {

        // soundcloud client ID
        var scClientId  = 'BLABLABLA';

        // initialize the SDK
        SC.initialize({
            client_id: scClientId,
            redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html"
        });

        SC.whenStreamingReady( function() {
            console.log('TOP DOWN');
        });

    };

});

// =============================================
})(jQuery);
```

compiled to: compiled-js-file.js

HTML file...

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <title>hi</title>
        <script src='jQuery.js'></script>
        <script src='compiled-js-file.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>html file</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

etc.

I've made a .jshintrc file in the base of the theme...

`"globals": {
    "SC": false
}`

and done the ol `/* globals: SC: true */`

But the .jshinrc doesn't seem to do anything and the comment gets me a
 `'SC' was used before it was defined.`

I'm no JavaScript expert... but I know that SC is an object... but that's also stored in a variable.. so - seems like it should work like a normal variable...

What am I doing wrong? or is this just a thing I have to suffer with? The code is all running as intended...  : ) ???

Comment: Try in lowercase `sc`

Comment: What js file are you including? we need more context, a reduced test case of the html file involved would be very helpful.

Comment: @erikvold - added some more detail for you. : ) 

Mustaghees - to no avail

Comment: Which file are you getting this warning on? The individual files? The combined file?

Comment: The compiled output. For this specific project, I had to use CodeKit to do the compiling.

Comment: @sheriffderek, can you provide full content of .jshintrc file, where analyzed js-file is placed relative to .jshintrc and how exactly do you invoke jshint?

Comment: My entire .jshintrc file is just that one-liner, that file is in the `/` root - and then the compiled / minified file is in `/js/min/script-name-min.js`   --- The root is a WordPress theme folder. I normally use EmberCLI or Brunch.io for my build tools, but because this is a WordPress structure, I'm having to use CodeKit.

Comment: I left out the minification process to see if that may be the culprit on CodeKits end, and if maybe things were getting jumbled - but it appears that this is not the case.

Comment: @sheriffderek okay try then to set SC using CodeKit UI: [Defining Globals](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#jshint)

Answer (score 4):

`SC` is defined in `window` object within [soundcloud JavaScript SDK](http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js): `window.SC=window.SC||{}`. There is an old [github issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/91) about troubles of identifying this kind of global objects by JSHint since it's typically not executing code but rather analyzing it. Telling JSHint about `SC` existance must solve issue. Correct syntax is described in JSHint [documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/). You should define variable using `predef` property in .jshintrc file:

```
{
  "predef": [ "SC" ]
}
```

Or using inline configuration like this:

```
/* global SC */
```

**Update:** If you are using CodeKit then try to [set globals using CodeKit UI](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#jshint). You need to put `SC` in Project Settings -> Syntax Checkers -> Custom Globals textfield. It looks like CodeKit use custom JSHint configuration, and configuration via .jshintrc [in not supported](https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit/issues/82) at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarified syntax, but I added both of these and the error still occurs.

Comment: Will do - really appreciate the help --- just got pulled to another project - so haven't had any time to check

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like you're including a soundcloud api js file, that may be the cause of this issue.

Comment: All of the mentioned js files are compiled into one master-scripts.js -- they are listed in the prepend section. The code all runs as intended / just getting the warning - so something might be out of order / or it might just need to be declared somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

it seems something wrong with the initialization of SC in the compiled js so that SC is "late" and initialized after that call. have you tried in another browser? is it the same result?

if it is the same, here is probably a some kind of a hacky solution to your problem:

```
//create a function so we can arrange a timer on it
function streamingReady(){
    if (type of SC != 'undefined') {
        SC.whenStreamingReady( function() {
            console.log('TOP DOWN');
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(streamingReady, 200);
    }
}
```

then in the former place of `SC.whenStreamingReady`, you call `streamingReady();`

hope it helps

Comment: also, can you try to change `$(document).ready` to `$(window).ready` first before trying the code above, see what happens

Comment: I've never used `$(window).ready()`  only `$(window).load()` but that seems to misfire sometimes.

Comment: I've heard that CodeKit can sometimes compile things in a whacky way. I will try your suggestion - and then also a different compiler.

Comment: Doesn't seem to love the `type of SC != 'undefined'`

Comment: @sheriffderek i'm not sure with what you mean misfire, but i never got problem with `$(window).ready()`, `$(window).load()` is a bit tricky, so i rarely use it. Btw, they are not the same, `$(window).load()` is executed earlier than `$(window).ready()`.

Comment: I have never seen `.ready` on the window in any production code, and I don't see any reference to it when I search --- but it sounds great - and I'll check it out for sure. By misfire... I mean - that I say... 'do this on window.load' and it doesn't do what I've told it to - *some of the time.

Comment: http://s.codepen.io/sheriffderek/debug/EjLYKP  In this test - it seems that ready executes before load. (console)

Comment: hmmm, then I must have mixed up with the timeline, but my point still true, the three of them is not the same, and executed at different time. by this point, I assume your problem still exists even after using `$(window).ready()`, then I am very sorry, I have no other idea other than that hacky script above, if you don't like the `type of` thing, maybe you could reverse the logic, or use `SC == null`, or just include the scripts just as it is, not compiled into one.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, SC takes time to load, I ended up using this code pattern:

```
WaitForSoundcloud();

function WaitForSoundcloud() {
    if(typeof SC == "undefined") {
        setTimeout(WaitForSoundcloud, 500);
    } else {

        SC.initialize({
          client_id: 'xxxxxxxx'
        });

        SC.oEmbed(track_url, {}).then(function(oEmbed) {
            console.log('oEmbed response: ', oEmbed);
        });
    }

}
```